# ServiceStack WSDL creates empty portType element

Tags: soap, wsdl, servicestack

I created a SOAP1.2 web service with ServiceStack. We have a client using the Axis2 platform to create a proxy class to our service via the WSDL; however, they are receiving an error because the portType does not contain any methods (all of our operations appear under the portType with name "ISyncReply").

`<wsdl:portType name="IOneWay"></wsdl:portType>`

If i manually edit the WSDL and remove the IOneWay port type and all the things that reference it, they are able to add their Axis2 classes just fine.

Is there any way to get ServiceStack to *not* output this PortType for Async if there are not any operations that are defined as asynchronous?

EDIT:
Also when trying to add a service reference using the wcftestclient it gives the following error; however, it appears to add the operations that exist under the

[image: The contract 'IOneWay' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract, or there is no valid method in this contract.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...

No, you cannot turn off the IOneWay port binding in the WSDL - It appears that [this template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Support/Templates/WsdlTemplateBase.cs?source=cc#L135) is used to generate the WSDL and the port binding is hard coded in the template (see line 135-137).